# Storing polygon soups

Tags: c++, data-structures, 3d, gis, mesh

I need to store large mesh information within a 3D system. The input is provided in a naive manner as a polygon soup (the exact format is [triangular irregular network](http://www.ems-i.com/wmshelp/Files/File_Formats/TIN_Files.htm))

If there are millions or tens of millions of vertices in such a soup, what is then the relatively efficient way of handling this data?
Using heap allocated structures is bad since it might hinder fluidity and alter cache coherency as compared to a more stack allocated old-school matrix. Storing data in arrays is usually the best thing to do, but in terms of querying useful information, this can be quite tedious and perhaps not worthwhile.

Hence, if I use a dedicated structure such as half edge or winged edge to store topology information, will this design alter the speed of some common operations done in geometric modeling and multiresolution methods? (more to the point, I want to apply wavelet analysis, edge collapses, subdivision and all of that "magic" to a big mesh - wavelets work with matrices, but those matrices are not easy to build without some special datastruct).

Comment: How about trying out the CGAL library? A huge amount of operations are defined already, it's written in C++, and emplated against different containers (list, vector, etc). You just need to translate the input in this case.

Comment: CGAL is huge and it has a steep learning curve. By simply looking at it for 10 minutes, I couldn't find out what it uses to speed up the work with those data structures (e.g. half edges). Apart from that, CGAL is quite famous and powerful, but it is a bit of a juggernaut.

Comment: Whenever I searched for "optimal solutions" questions/answers here, most of the answers were saying that profiling is always required with complex algorithms and datastructures. Depending on what I'm programming, if the underlying algorithm and datastructure are complex, I try to find a library that has all this, to avoid debugging and developing stuff that already exists.. but that's just my strategy..  :)

Comment: Indeed, but statistically there is a preferred choice for a design when it comes to this kind of problems. Usually, people have had experience with it already and can tell beforehand what path to follow. From my experience, a designed that's profiled and found to be flawed is a big setback, hence my question - I can't start a side quest atm: profiling two methods and see for myself - instead, lazily even, I was relying on common knowledge for a first big "heads up". Anyhow, point taken!

Comment: For reasonably *"working"* with the mesh I would indeed suggest to use something more sophisiticated than mere indexed vertex arrays. Take a look at [OpenMesh](http://www.openmesh.org/). They use a half edge datastructure, but with all the data stored in a bunch of large arrays, nothing fragmenting your heap. If you are familiar (and fond of) the C++ standard library's design principles and modern C++ in general, you will immediately feel at home with OpenMesh, which extensively uses templates and iterators to provide an easy to use generic interface, yet with an efficient implementation.

Comment: Oh.. I get it now... you might want to ask on the Computational Science site as well, maybe someone there has dealt with this and tell you more... good luck!

Comment: @tomislav-maric thanks, I'll ask the community there!
at ChristianRau thanks, that sounds like the image I had in mind for an optimized struc.